# Ruby odd number of arguments for hash error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
case look
  when 'side'
        hash1 = {
            'num' => 5,
            'style' => 'sideStyle',
        }

  when 'front'
        hash1 = {
            'num' => 8,
            'style' => 'frontStyle',
        }

  when 'back'
        hash1 = {
            'num' => 4,
            'style' => 'backStyle',
            'special' => 'yes',
        }

  else
        hash1 = {
            'num' => 2,
            'style' => 'noStyle',
        }
  end

  myStyle = Hash[hash1]
```

My piece of code looks like this.

when I run this code I get "odd number of arguments for Hash".

is this the correct way to from an hash? could someone please help me how to get it resolved.

Comment: I think you were on the right track. What you have will work fine if you change `myStyle = Hash[hash1]` to `myStyle = hash1`. You're repeating yourself, but it would work. @mudasobwa's first case statement example would be an improvement for you.

Comment: @DerekHopper Shouldn't `myStyle = Hash[hash1]` be equivalent to `myStyle = hash1`? If I'm not mistaken, `Hash` is supposed to [use `to_hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) which is supposed to [return `self`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-to_hash). And I can't reproduce their error with their code.

Comment: @StefanPochmann You're right. It looks like the issue could be elsewhere, right? The case statement seems like it's fine the way it's shown in the question. Maybe Lokesh can share where they use the results of this case statement.

Comment: @DerekHopper Oh, I think looked at that wrong, `Hash[hash1]` isn't `Kernel::Hash` but `Hash::[]`. And [many years ago](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1385), that wanted key/value pairs and didn't yet know what to do with a hash argument. So I guess the OP uses a very old Ruby, as also indicated by the rails 3 tag. Lokesh, what Ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Too much of a hash initializations in a row. Just assign the result of `case` to the value:

```
my_style = 
  case look
  when 'side'
        {
            'num' => 5,
            'style' => 'sideStyle',
        }

  when 'front'
        {
            'num' => 8,
            'style' => 'frontStyle',
        }

  when 'back'
        {
            'num' => 4,
            'style' => 'backStyle',
            'special' => 'yes',
        }

  else
        {
            'num' => 2,
            'style' => 'noStyle',
        }
  end
```

---

To DRY, I personally would better do:

```
result = 
  case look
  when 'side' then [5, "sideStyle"] 
  when 'front' then [8, "frontStyle"] 
  when 'back' then [4, "backStyle", "yes"] 
  else [2, "noStyle"]
  end 
result.zip(%w|num style special|).map(&:rotate).to_h
```

Comment: Any idea why they get their "odd number of arguments" error? How do your ways prevent that? And about your second way, why include `nil` only to `compact` it away?

Comment: `Hash[1,2]`
 => `{1=>2}`
Probably not what you want

Comment: @StefanPochmann they called `Hash[hash]` with a single hash as an argument. I don’t call `Hash[]`, I return a hash instead. `nil` is needed for `back` case, there are three elements in a hash.

Comment: @DonPaulie I do not follow.

Comment: @engineersmnky I finally got what you all are talking about `nil`s :) Thanks all, removed.